# How to extract a node from xml string C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have am xml string like mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NodeA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.air-watch.com/webapi/resources">
    <AdditionalInfo>
        <Links>
            <Link xsi:type="link">
            </Link>
        </Links>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <TotalResults>100</TotalResults>
    <NodeB>
        <NodeC>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <A>valueA</A>
            <B>valueB</B>
        </NodeC>
        <NodeC>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <A>valueA</A>
            <B>valueA</B>
        </NodeC>
   </NodeB>
</NodeA>
```

I want to extract NodeB and its child nodes (NodeC elements). How can I do it? Below solution does somewhat similar operation but it needs the xml string to be loaded in a XDocument first:

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
String response=doc.Elements("question")
                   .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id")==id)
                   .Single()
                   .Element("response")
                   .Value;
```

Is there a way to do it without having to load it in a doc? Some operation on string object itself.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using an `XDocument`? Operations on strings are not XML-based. You want an XML API. LINQ to XML is a very good XML API.

Comment: xdocument or string, your still storing the whole thing in memory.  Why the restriction?

Comment: hmm, if avoiding loading into a XDocument does not make any difference in memory or performance, I think I am going to go ahead and do it that way.

Answer (score -2):

Why cant you use this

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
String response=doc.Elements("question")
                   .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id")==id)
                   .Single()
                   .Element("response")
                   .Value; ?
```

you can use Regular Expressions then.

Comment: I am still not able to get the node I am interested in. Can you please post the final Linq to XML?